# How to have the same value in the model and view without [(ngModel)]?

Tags: arrays, angular, input

I have list of ranges, and before update model I have validation. Current range can't be less than previous and bigger than next.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of ranges>
 <td>
          <input
            #fromRange
            type="number"
            [ngModel]="row.fromRange"
            (focusout)="rangeChanged(fromRange.value, index, true)" 
          /> 
            -
          <input
            #toRange
            [ngModel]="row.toRange"
            (focusout)="rangeChanged(toRange.value, index, false)" 
            type="number"
          />
 </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

The second range was 51-100. This is after the change.

If you want to change the second row, as in the picture, you will get an error message, it is not possible for the number to be greater than 100. So the value in the model remains 51, but in the input field it is still 151.

[(ngModel)] is not the solution, because I can't allow user to change value without validation.

How to change it so that the value in view is the same as in model ?

Comment: just update `row.fromRange` and, because it is bound, the value inside of the input should also update

Answer (score 1):

Since we are not using `[(ngModel)]` to manage the FormControl, we ourselves have to take care of syncing the model and view data.

One possible solution would be to manually update the input value in case of error.

Within html file:

```js
(focusout)="rangeChanged(fromRange, index, true)"
```

Within ts file:

```ts
rangeChanged(inputEle: HTMLInputElement, index: number, isFromRangeChanged: boolean) {
    let hasError: boolean;
    const rangeProperty = isFromRangeChanged ? 'fromRange' : 'toRange';
    // Validation logic that sets the hasError value

    if (hasError) {
      // Error logic goes here...

      inputEle.value = this.ranges[index][rangeProperty];
    } else {
      this.ranges[index][rangeProperty] = inputEle.value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, this is the solution i was looking for

Comment: The same behavior as `(focusout)` can also be achieved with:
`(ngModelChange)="rangeChanged(fromRange, index, true)" 
 [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`